# How to optimize the following Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have the following Database Structure

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "record")
public class SearchRecord {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
private String vidName;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> videoLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and would like to run a Hibernate query that filters out all SearchRecords that match/contain 1..n videoLabels. (only objects that match all of the videoLabels!)

I came up with the following solution - in this case matchin five label names

```
SELECT DISTINCT a
FROM SearchRecord a JOIN
     a.labels b JOIN
     a.labels c JOIN
     a.labels d JOIN
     a.labels e JOIN
     a.labels f
WHERE b.name = 'Fire alarm' and
      c.name = 'Speech' and
      d.name = 'bus' and
      e.name = 'cup' and
      f.name = 'dog'
```

I suppose that's the worst query you could come up with for such a scenario having five join operations. Is there a way on otpimizing the query?

Comment: Do you need another table for label? Can It be just another column in SearchRecord, then your query will be easy.

Comment: That query is invalid SQL. You need to specify join conditions in the `JOIN` clause.  You also don't seem to have any join condition between `searchrecord` and `labels`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually it's reading mistake i thought they used keyword "NATURAL"

Comment: the mysql documentation states: When using join or inner join, the on condition is optional

Comment: I followed the Hibernate example on https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-query-elementcollection/ however I am required to filter out all SearchRecords that match all 1..n provided label names.

Comment: so if I understood you right, there's no way to optimize the given query given under the current data model? Any hints welcome....